# Create Proxy Class from Dynamics 365 CRM SDK

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have tried to create proxy class from Dynamics 365 CRM SDK using CrmSvcUtil. For that I have download the latest SDK and tried to generate proxy class but it causing error in console: "Unable to login CRM".
**Below is the syntax I am using:**

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://<servername>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc 
/out:myorganizationcrmsdktypes.cs /username:"<domain\username>" /password:"<password>" 
/namespace:"proxy.crm" /serviceContextName:"CRMContext"
```

I have also tried with the XRMTool to generate the cs file but Same error occurred.

Comment: Are you using `"` in the command or it is just marker here? in a username and password parameters

Comment: it is just a marker only. In command line I just wrote with plain text

Comment: Are you able to login to crm org with plugin regn tool or xrmtoolbox ? Make sure org url & creds are correct. Any proxy limitation?

Comment: Any corporate network proxy limitation?

Comment: @ArunVinoth , Yes I am able to login from Xrmtoolbox but while trying to generate proxy class, It showing error that "Unable to login to CRM"

Answer (score 0):

Try `... /username:username /password:password /domain:domain`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `/interactivelogin:true` which will open a window & authenticate your org.

[MS forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/184949) & [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx#bkmk_parameters)

Comment: I have tried with interactivelogin:true and it still shows same error. And also checked that there is not any proxy limitation.

Comment: Did you try other options like mentioned in link - nuget update? @C.Thaker

Comment: Yes, I have tried to download Nuget package but not able to generate the proxy class. and getting same issue as above.